# R Create visit number for each subject based on visit date

Tags: r

**I have a long data frame with multiple visits per subject based on visits to the hospital.**

| ID | VISIT_DATE | COPD | DIABETES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1965-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1989-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-02-10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1995-01-01 | 1 | 1 |

**I wanted to make a new variable called "VISIT_NUMBER" in which I can consecutively number which visit it is for each subject.**

| ID | VISIT_DATE | COPD | DIABETES | VISIT_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1965-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1989-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-02-10 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1995-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I have used dplyr in the past for something like this but I am stumped on where to go next.

Comment: Try with `cumsum(df$ID == 1)`

Answer (score 3):

### base R

```r
dat$VISIT_NUMBER <- ave(dat$ID, dat$ID, FUN=seq_along)
dat
#   ID VISIT_DATE COPD DIABETES VISIT_NUMBER
# 1  1 2020-01-01    1        0            1
# 2  2 1965-01-01    0        0            1
# 3  3 1989-01-01    0        0            1
# 4  1 2020-02-10    1        1            2
# 5  2 1970-01-01    0        1            2
# 6  3 1995-01-01    1        1            2
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(VISIT_NUMBER = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, VISIT_NUMBER := seq_len(.N), by = .(ID)]
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), VISIT_DATE = c("2020-01-01", "1965-01-01", "1989-01-01", "2020-02-10", "1970-01-01", "1995-01-01"), COPD = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), DIABETES = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), VISIT_NUMBER = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option with `rowid`

```
> setDT(df)[, VISIT_NUMBER := rowid(ID)][]
   ID VISIT_DATE COPD DIABETES VISIT_NUMBER
1:  1 2020-01-01    1        0            1
2:  2 1965-01-01    0        0            1
3:  3 1989-01-01    0        0            1
4:  1 2020-02-10    1        1            2
5:  2 1970-01-01    0        1            2
6:  3 1995-01-01    1        1            2
```

Comment: I'm still adopting `data.table`'s many helper funcs like this one. `rleid` is a favorite of mine :-)